# Modal con password (Implementar)

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, modal

Necesito implementar un modal con password, de modo que al clickar en un elemento despliegue el modal. y si pones correctamente el password puedes acceder. Mi problema es que al poner el link a la página que quiero que vaya no funciona.

Os dejo el código HTML del modal.

```
<!-- Modal Password -->

<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Enter the password to access</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
        </div>
        <form id="loginForm"> <!-- form with an ID so we can identify it, now includes both the textbox and the button within it -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="modalpass" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="modalpass" class="form-control" id="modalpass">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Y el código JS del modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var pass1="letmein";

$('#loginModal').modal('show');
$('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  window.location.href = '../index.html'
});

//handle the form's "submit" event
$("#loginForm").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //stop a full postback

  var password = $("#modalpass").val(); //get the entered value from the password box

  if (password == pass1)
    alert('Access Granted!');
  else {
    alert('Password is incorrect.');
    //window.location = "/index.html";
  }
});
```

});

Aquí os dejo también un link a la página en el servidor para ver como se ve (el link modal estaría en la imagen de "Newfront", que no funciona):

https://jimenacastro.net/

Espero y me podáis ayudar. Un saludo!

Comment: el evento on submit si se esta ejecutando?

Comment: En teoría si se está ejecutando, aunque no controlo mucho de JavaScript. Al clickar en el elemento si aparece el modal pero al introducir el password no redirige a la página que quiero mostrar.